# Set int64 value to *int64 pointer

Tags: json, go, pointers, null

I need map the struct to create a JSON structure. The collector_id attribute in JSON should be able to take null value or int value.
I hace the follow code:

```
type purchaseInfo struct {
    CollectorID *int64 `json:"collector_id"`
}

func mapPurchaseInfo(collectorID int64) purchaseInfo {
    var collectorIDToSend *int64
    if collectorID < 0 {
        collectorIDToSend = nil
    } else {
        collectorIDToSend = collectorID
    }

    return purchaseInfo{
        CollectorID: collectorIDToSend,
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile, the collectorID can't be assigned to collectorIDToSend.
Is there a way to be able to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can take the address of the `collectorID` param: `collectorIDToSend = &collectorID`. This is how the function may be simplified: `func mapPurchaseInfo(collectorID int64) (r purchaseInfo) { if collectorID >= 0 { r.CollectorID = &collectorID }; return }` Try it here: https://go.dev/play/p/lRxqcarlfRe

Comment: Hi! If i do that, Would not the CollectorID value take the address instead the int value?

Comment: @ZottoSL: that is exactly what a pointer is. Pointers are also covered in the [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the declaration of the mapPurchaseInfo function, to correctly assign the value passed in parameter to collectorIDToSend, the & operator must be used to retrieve the memory address of collectorID.
- When constructing the purchaseInfo return variable, it is possible to put the fields of the structure directly as in the example.

```golang
type purchaseInfo struct {
        CollectorID *int64 `json:"collector_id"`
    }

    func mapPurchaseInfo(collectorID int64) purchaseInfo {
        var collectorIDToSend *int64
        if collectorID < 0 {
            collectorIDToSend = nil
        } else {
            collectorIDToSend = &collectorID
        }

        return purchaseInfo{
            CollectorID: collectorIDToSend,
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! If i do that, Would not the CollectorID value take the address instead the int value?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!
collectorIDToSend is a pointer variable, it will point to the memory address where the collectorID variable is located , the value stored in the memory address will be the int value of collectorID not the address it self.
When returning purchaseInfo struct, CollectorID field of struct will be assigned the value of collectorIDToSend, So CollectorID will take the address where the collectorID value stored instead of the value it self.

Comment: You can use the * operator to get the value stored at the memory address pointed to by a pointer variable. So, you could use *collectorIDToSend to get the value of collectorID.

Answer (score -2):

```html
type purchaseInfo struct {
    CollectorID *int64 `json:"collector_id"`
}

func mapPurchaseInfo(collectorID *int64) purchaseInfo {
    if *collectorID < 0 {
        return purchaseInfo{CollectorID: nil}
    }
    return purchaseInfo{
        CollectorID: collectorID,
    }
}
```